# Make global variables available to an included file within a function

Tags: php

I need to include files within a function, and files use lots of variables defined earlier in the script.  Using global is not an option because it is impossible to say which variables will be used in included files.  The only one real solution is to make all global variables accessible in function, something like:

```
     function finc($file)
    {

        foreach($GLOBALS as $k=>$v)
        {
            $$k=$v;
        } 
        include $file;
   }
```

but it won't be good when using lots of files with lots of variables, so is there any better way to do it?

Comment: @user410572: "the only one real solution is to make all global variables accessible in function": global variables are already accessible inside the function. That's why they are global.

Comment: I'd start at the root cause of the problem: _'it is impossible to say which variables will be used in included files.'_ I'd solve that first, possibly setting handpicked variables in an array and feeding that as an argument to the function (possibly using `extract` internally for the time being)

Comment: @MainMa, it's not. You have to use `global $some_global_var` or `$GLOBALS['some_global_var']` for that.

Comment: As you have noticed, things are getting quite hairy. Could you give more context to your problem so that we can advise a reasonable redesign?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Thats right. PHP is really weird sometimes.

Comment: If you've got so many global variables that you can't tell which functions need access to which globals, you have a *seriously* flawed design and you should refactor your code if possible.

Comment: @MainMa, you might have been thinking of superglobals.

Comment: @erisco: no, what I wanted to say is that a global variable can already be accessed from anywhere through `$GLOBALS[...]`. But I see now that this is not related to the question.

Comment: This looks like bad design to me.

Comment: it is large working project so rewriting all the code is unreal. extracting all variables into the function is only way for now, and i've tested the speed - it slows down the site only for 0,05 - 0,1 sec, and its acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no good answer for that problem.
only an advice. use objects...
what you are doing is possible but in my opinion a very bad solution because you are defining all globals. there is however a more efficient way to do that: `extract($GLOBALS)`, but it would be better to use `$GLOBALs['whatever']` in your included scripts...

Answer (score 2):

Beware: you're really importing all global variables.

```
extract($GLOBALS);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for templateing then you shall provide the template only a "context", not all global variables. Simply specify an array of variables that should be accessible in the template and `extract` them.

If it isn't templateing what you do, but routing you should think about returning the file name to include:

```
include getPathForPage('home');
```